# InterstitialAd in Android Studio is not showing

Tags: android, android-studio, admob, interstitial

I'm developing a mobile app and the interstitial ad is not showing.

I have declared the ad and this is the code

```
private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_myactivity);

    MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
        }
    });


    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

    InterstitialAd.load(this, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712", adRequest, new InterstitialAdLoadCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded(@NonNull InterstitialAd interstitialAd) {
            // The mInterstitialAd reference will be null until
            // an ad is loaded.
            mInterstitialAd = interstitialAd;
            Log.i(TAG, "onAdLoaded");

            mInterstitialAd.setFullScreenContentCallback(new FullScreenContentCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onAdClicked() {
                    // Called when a click is recorded for an ad.
                    Log.d(TAG, "Ad was clicked.");
                }

                @Override
                public void onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
                    // Called when ad is dismissed.
                    // Set the ad reference to null so you don't show the ad a second time.
                    Log.d(TAG, "Ad dismissed fullscreen content.");
                    mInterstitialAd = null;
                }

                @Override
                public void onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(AdError adError) {
                    // Called when ad fails to show.
                    Log.e(TAG, "Ad failed to show fullscreen content.");
                    mInterstitialAd = null;
                }

                @Override
                public void onAdImpression() {
                    // Called when an impression is recorded for an ad.
                    Log.d(TAG, "Ad recorded an impression.");
                }

                @Override
                public void onAdShowedFullScreenContent() {
                    // Called when ad is shown.
                    Log.d(TAG, "Ad showed fullscreen content.");
                }
            });
        }
        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(@NonNull LoadAdError loadAdError) {
            Log.i(TAG, loadAdError.getMessage());
            mInterstitialAd = null;
        }
    });

 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             openInterstitial();
        }
    });

}

public void openInterstitial() {
 if (mInterstitialAd != null) {
        mInterstitialAd.show(myactivity.this);
    } else {
        Log.d("TAG", "The interstitial ad wasn't ready yet.");
    }
}
```

I have implemented the ad following the Google AdMob documentation, I don't know why the ad doesn't load.

I tried to pass the second activity when I call to mInterstitialAd.show but I get an error

Comment: Did you see anything in logs?

Comment: I have these two errors in logs: 2022-07-12 06:00:21.137 19720-19783/com.package.app E/Ads: Timeout waiting for show call succeed to be called.
2022-07-12 06:00:21.142 19720-19720/com.package.app E/MainActivity: Ad failed to show fullscreen content.

Comment: I suggest to put a breakpoint into `onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent` and check `AdError` message and other data

Answer (score 1):

Try this!

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
     InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    
            Button btn= findViewById(R.id.btn_ads);
    
            btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    InterstitialAd.load(MainActivity.this,"ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712", adRequest,
                            new InterstitialAdLoadCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onAdLoaded(@NonNull InterstitialAd interstitialAd) {
                                    // The mInterstitialAd reference will be null until
                                    // an ad is loaded.
                                    mInterstitialAd = interstitialAd;
                                    Log.i("TAG", "onAdLoaded");
                                }
    
                                @Override
                                public void onAdFailedToLoad(@NonNull LoadAdError loadAdError) {
                                    // Handle the error
                                    Log.d("TAG", loadAdError.toString());
                                    mInterstitialAd = null;
                                }
                            });
    
    
                    if (mInterstitialAd != null) {
                        mInterstitialAd.show(MainActivity.this);
                    } else {
                        Log.d("TAG", "The interstitial ad wasn't ready yet.");
                    }
                }
            });
    
    
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).